# How to add list to dropdown from api in react native ios?

Tags: javascript, react-native, dropdown, react-native-ios

I am using following dropdown in react native : [react-native-selectme](https://github.com/gs-akhan/react-native-select)

```
    render() {
       return (
         <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Select width={250} ref="SELECT1" optionListRef={this._getOptionList.bind(this)} defaultValue="Select a Province in Canada ..." onSelect={this._selectItem.bind(this)}>
            <Option value={ {id : "alberta"}}>Alberta</Option>
            <Option>British Columbia</Option>
            <Option>Manitoba</Option>
            <Option>New Brunswick</Option>
            <Option>Newfoundland and Labrador</Option>
            <Option>Northwest Territories</Option>
            <Option>Nova Scotia</Option>
            <Option>Nunavut</Option>
            <Option>Ontario</Option>
            <Option>Prince Edward Island</Option>
            <Option>Quebec</Option>
            <Option>Saskatchewan</Option>
            <Option>Yukon</Option>
          </Select>

          <Text>Selected Canadas province: {this.state.selected_value}</Text>

          <OptionList ref="OPTIONLIST" />
         </View>
       );

     }
  };
```

But here `optionList` is hardcoded. I want to add my `array` into this `dropdown`.

**Array:**

```
tempArray: [{
  vehicle_no: 'M111',
  vehicle_id: 111
}, {
  vehicle_no: 'M222',
  vehicle_id: 222
}]
```

I am new to `react-native`, please guide me for better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to map your array ?
Something like:

```
<Select .....>
  { 
    tempArray.map(item => {
      return(
        <Option value={item.vehicle_id}>{item.vehicle_no}</Option>
      )
    });
  }
</Select>
```

Comment: I have made changes as you said but it gives me error. `Unexpected token` for adding render method again in code. so that I have edited my code of question, can you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: My bad, it's return not render. Fixed it above.

Comment: @ Roc Khalil: Still it gives me `Syntax Error`